# How can I update symlink for libc.so.6 on RedHat?

Tags: symlink, libc

I am trying to update the symlink libc.so.6. It correctly points to libc-2.17.so. I need to make it point to libc-2.18.so. I tried to do a rm of the symlink but then nothing worked. I also tried to unlink the symlink.

How can I update the symlink ? I have seen multiple questions asked but nothing worked for me (including ldconfig).

I hope someone has an answer.

Comment: Can you post the full path of your actual symlink and the libc-2.8.so location?

Comment: The libc.so.6 is at /lib64/libc.s0.6. It points to /lib64/libc-2.17.so at the moment. I installed the latest glibc 2.18 and put it in /lib64/libc-2.18.so.

Comment: Note that changing the file name of the library will not have any immediate effect.  For example, if you get an error regarding the `GLIBC_2.18` symbol version, the error will remain after this change.

Comment: @FlorianWeimer  - Are you suggesting renaming the /lib64/libc-2.17 to /lib64/libc-2.18 ?

Comment: @ksoop, I think you are trying to solve a different problem, and changing the symlink will not help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I update the symlink?

You need to understand that GLIBC consists of several hundred files, and symlinks must be updated for *all* of them at once.

If you update `libc.so.6` symlink, but don't update `ld-linux*` at the same time, all your dynamically linked programs will fail to run. Ditto for `libpthread.so`, `libdl.so`, etc. etc.

The most likely end result of making mistakes here is an unbootable system, that must be restored with a rescue disk or a complete reinstall.

The best way to perform this operation is to let your package manager do it.

If you can't do that, then your best bet is to boot from an alternate disk, mount your root filesystem into e.g. `/mnt` and do `make install DESTDIR=/mnt`.

Comment: sudo yum -y update glibc does not update from 2-17 to a newer version. Is there anyway I can tell it to update to 2.18 ?

Comment: @ksoop no, becasue CentOS distribution doesn't upgrade version to 2.18 on the release.

Answer (score -1):

First of all you you have to do a ls -l /lib64/libc* to see all the links and libc libraries

Then do:

```
cd /lib64
unlink libc.so.6
/sbin/sln /lib64/libc-2.18.so /lib64/libc.so.6
```

That should do it.

Please keep in mind that when you unlink **libc.so.6** nothing will really work on your server. No **ls**, no **cp**, not even **ln**. So you have to use **sln** instead (sln is a statically linked version of ln)

Comment: Thanks Bogdan. I am going to try this and I will let you know the results.

Comment: This *will not work* because `/lib/ld-linux*` (pointing to `/lib/ld-2.x.so`) must match `libc-2.x.so` *at all times*, or *every* dynamically linked binary will fail to run (likely rendering the system unbootable).

Comment: @EmployedRussian and Bogdan - That did not work. I am stuck trying to update glibc from 2-17 to 2-18 and higher. I cant seem to proceed without it. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Clearly you're doing something wrong or we're missing something (like in not having all the details or a complete list with all the links that are supposed to be created in there). It's pretty hard to do it like this...